# Osclass - Facebook Plugin ERRO

Tags: osclass

I can not register with Facebook, have tested all plugin versions and all is on this tab. How can I fix? After Verifying on Facebook he goes to this tab and not the right

[image]
<sub>(source: [gforum.tv](http://img.gforum.tv/img/61fe6a10fc4caa5774388d1e11d407075b223bf4.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Please only submit questions that are related to software development. A good point to start is the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi,
Do you have any PHP errors poping somewhere ?
Make sure that your redirect URL in you Facebook app is correctly set up.